# PyQt Tabs Widget Not connecting

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, qt-creator, connector

I'm new to PyQT and GUI dev in general, I'm getting grasp of the connectors but the Tabs Widget I can't seem to make work.

I'm trying this code:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.tabsFrame, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("tabBarClicked(int)")), self.myFunction)
```

(auto generated by the QtCreator)

but I doesn't seem to do anything.

The buttons I can make work because they have the 'new' syntax (button.clicked.connect(function), but this don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using a PyQt/Qt version that is too old.

The [`tabBarClicked`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#tabBarClicked) signal was only introduced in Qt5.2, and because of the old-style syntax your're probably using PyQt4 (as in PyQt5 `QObject.connect` is gone).

You're not getting an error because in old-style PyQt4, signals are [defined implicitly](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html#pyqt4-signals-and-qt-signals) when used, so your code works, but the signal is just never emitted.

You could just use the [`currentChanged`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) signal instead.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the PyQt5.2 was only for Python 3.3 the file name is a bit misleading in their website. I'll take a look anyway.

The currentChanged worked too! Thanks.